# Задача по авторизации

Tags: php, javascript

Допустим такую ситуацию. Пользователь сделал авторизацию (прописались куки, которые будут активны до нажатия кнопки выход).
Далее пользователь делает серфинг по страницам сайта и т.д.
Потом он нажимает выход (и куки, созданые ранее, удаляются).
Но как только он жмет стрелку "назад" в браузере, то он без проблем смотрит странички сайта, которые были доступны только зарегистрированному пользователю.
Получается, что я не могу сохранить информацию пользователя в секрете.

***Вопрос: как правильно поступить, чтобы при нажатии на стрелку "назад" пользователь увидел форму авторизации?***

Comment: Я не прошу готовое решение. Подскажите направление???

Comment: Это нормальное поведение. Зачем что-то менять?

Посмотрите на [это решение](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20044710)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как голый вариант:
Нажатие на кнопку назад отслеживать через js и им же делать запрос на сервер, выяснить, авторизован ли юзер. После получения ответа страницу можно обновить.